# JQuery: Loop through elements and set as variable for outside scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve a DOM element from an array, and I want to set it as a variable to use outside its scope. Right now, my variable `future_devices` returns one object as expected. But my other variable `future_device` returns the object when the current DOM should have returned `[]` due to my last `if` statement. I originally tried to declare my variables as `var` due to scope but that did not help. Here is my code:

```js
var future_devices = $('.hardware .future-hardware')

if (future_devices.length) {

  let future_device = $(future_devices)
    .each(function() {

      let device = this
      let device_work_order = $(device)
        .data(
          'work-order'
        )

      if (device_work_order == data['new_host']['work_order']) {

        return device

      }

    })
```

I can tell you on the said DOM, the two variables I am using to compare have the following values:

> device_work_order = 3MOD0

> data['new_host']['work_order'] = 3MOD9

So since `future_devices` returns only one object and my last `if` statement is not true, I should get [], right?

Comment: can you also share your html element structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(...)` is returning the jQuery collection and always will regardless. So an assignment statement using `.each()` is the wrong approach.

**Solution**: Assign the return of `.filter()` instead. Filter is designed to accomplish your goal. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector)

NOTE: You should realize that if there is more than one match, it will return the entire collection of matches. In the code below I show only the first match, but since there are two matches (for demonstration), you'll see that both matches are returned.

```js
const future_devices = $('.hardware .future-hardware');
const data = {new_host: {work_order: 333}};

const future_device = $(future_devices)
  .filter(function(idx, el) {
    let device_work_order = $(el).data('work-order');
    if (device_work_order == data['new_host']['work_order']) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  })
console.log("First match only: ", future_device[0]); // First match
console.log("Collection: ",future_device); // All matches
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hardware">
  <div class="future-hardware" data-work-order="111">111</div>
</div>
<div class="hardware">
  <div class="future-hardware" data-work-order="333">First Match</div>
</div>
<div class="hardware">
  <div class="future-hardware" data-work-order="111">111</div>
</div>
<div class="hardware">
  <div class="future-hardware" data-work-order="333">Second Match</div>
</div>
<div class="hardware">
  <div class="future-hardware" data-work-order="111">111</div>
</div>
<div class="hardware">
  <div class="future-hardware" data-work-order="111">111</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your solution and this gave me the results I was looking for! I actually saw this function previously and I attempted to use it, but I could not get it working either. I think my main problem was I was not utilizing the function() and returning an object. I guess I also don't fully understand the .each() method.

But thank you for your response! Since then, I've utilized this method vs. .each() else where in my code that seemed more appropriate and using the "return" functionality